# automatically populate the url link when pasted in textareainput in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a small dummy application with textareaInput. Right now the user can input anything he wants inside this box. Can we have put a link so that it highlights. For example when the user puts `This is the link : https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/defaultinterstitial.cms`  , the link here should be populate as a link and not as a text

```
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    textAreaInput("caption", "Caption", "Data Summary", width = "1000px"),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  )
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$value <- renderText({ input$caption })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
  
}
```

Comment: A user can enter both free text and link in the text box and you want it to highlight only when it is a link and display as it is when it's a text?

Comment: Yeah right . Some thing like this ...................... This is the link : https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/defaultinterstitial.cms

Comment: If you see here, "This is a link" is a text and then the link ??? Got it ?

Comment: What if user enters abc ?

Comment: It should consider as text

Comment: So how do you know if a value is a url or text ? What is the logic to identify that? What if user enters abc.ca ?

Comment: great question. Even I am thinking. Is there a way to highlight only if it is a valid URL. For example, if you google abc.ca the page does not exist. Right? So only if it is a valid URL, it has to highlight

Comment: Actually, how to identify if a url is a valid url is a different question altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want

```
library(stringr)
library(spsUtil)
library(glue)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    textAreaInput("caption", "Caption", "Data Summary", width = "1000px"),
    uiOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    url <- reactive({
        req(input$caption)
        list(
            match = str_match_all(input$caption, "http[s]{0,1}://[^ ]+") %>% unlist(), 
            url = input$caption
        )
    }) %>% debounce(1000)
    output$value <- renderUI({
        req(url()$url)
        formater <- function(x){glue::glue("<a href='{x}'>{str_remove(x, 'http[s]{0,1}://')}</a>")}
        url <- url()$url
        for(i in url()$match) {
            if(quiet(checkUrl(i, timeout = 0.5))){
                url <- str_replace(url, i, formater)
            }
        }
        p(
            HTML(url)
        )
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Explain:

This works no matter what you put inside the textarea, along as some text starts with `http(s)`, then it will pass to a URL checker and try to reach the URL. If successful, then formats the string to be a link and remove `http(s)://`.

First text is processed inside `url` reactive to find all the possible URLs. It has a debounce of 1000, meaning we only check for URLs at most 1 once per second. If users keep typing, it will only be checked every 1 s.

The reactive is passed to the UI rendering part. Here we use `quiet` and `checkUrl` from {[spsUtil](https://github.com/lz100/spsUtil)} package to silently check URLs with a timeout of 0.5 second (if we can't get it within 0.5 s, return FALSE).

If the url is okay, then we replace the original text with a link.

try `https://www.google.com sdasd http://apple.com ssd https://random.as.com`

It should give you following
[image]

Comment: Hi. I tried with your sentence. But still not getting converted to links. I am not able to paste the screenshot here.:(

Comment: try to use `spsUtil::checkUrl(YOUR_URL, timeout = 0.5)`, if you get `FALSE`, that means it is your internet problem. These URLs are not reachable from your computer.